# Put substring as key and the following substring as value into a TreeMap

Tags: java, substring, treemap

Example:

```
String wholeString = 
"Typical models for star formation assume that every type of galaxy produces stars"
```

I'd like to store the splitted string and its following (+1) String in a treemap:
with `windowSize = 4` (predefined):
`Typi`,`ypic` -> put into TreeMap
`ypic`,`pica` -> put into TreeMap

for `windowSize = 2` it would look like this:
`Ty`,`yp` -> TreeMap

and so on.

My code so far:

```
    Map<String, String> generateMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < wholeString.length(); i++) {
        generateMap
                .put((wholeString.substring((i),
                        Math.min((i + windowSize), wholeString.length()))),
                        (wholeString.substring(
                                (i + 1),
                                (Math.min((i + windowSize),
                                        wholeString.length())))));

    }
```

If I sysprint it, I gets this:
`{ Augen=Augen,  Außen=Außen,  Innen=Innen,  Jauch=Jauch,`and so on

Comment: Don't put so many instructions on a single line. It makes your code hard to read and difficult to debug. Try to split each operation in a separate value. It's likely you will find your bug yourself.

Comment: I, to the contrary, like exactly OP's style. So, @dfdfdf, leave the code as it is :) You do have an excess of parentheses, though.

Comment: Your sample output has nothing to do with the `wholeString`. Fix that, please. Do you regard spaces as delimiters, or like any other char? In other words, do you want `al m`, `l mo` -> put into TreeMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take:

```
final String wholeString =
  "Typical models for star formation assume that every type of galaxy produces stars";
final int windowSize = 4;
final Map<String, String> generateMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

final int limit = wholeString.length() - windowSize;
for (int i = 0; i < limit;) generateMap.put(
      wholeString.substring(i, i + windowSize),
      wholeString.substring(++i, i + windowSize));

for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : generateMap.entrySet())
  System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go (I changed the TreeMap by a LinkedHashMap for debug purposes, you can put back the TreeMap if your prefer):

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> generateMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        String wholeString = "Typical models for star formation assume that every type of galaxy produces stars";
        int windowSize = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < wholeString.length(); i++) {
            int start = i;
            int end = Math.min(i + windowSize, wholeString.length());
            int start1 = Math.min(i + 1, wholeString.length() - 1);
            int end1 = Math.min(i + 1 + windowSize, wholeString.length());
            generateMap.put(wholeString.substring(start, end), wholeString.substring(start1, end1));

        }
        System.err.println(generateMap);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like recursion, you may try this:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Subs {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void func(Map<String,String> map, String input, int windowSize) {
        if (input.length() <= windowSize) {
            map.put(input, input);
            return;
        } else {
            map.put(input.substring(0, windowSize), input.substring(1, windowSize + 1));
            func(map, input.substring(1), windowSize);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String wholeString = "Typical models for star formation assume that every type of galaxy produces stars";
        Map<String,String> ourMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        int windowSize = 4;
        func(ourMap, wholeString, windowSize);
        System.out.print(ourMap);
    }
}
```

Please note that I'm using 'LinkedHashMap', so output will be in order you put values into it. If you need to put into a TreeMap, simply replace LinkedHashMap with TreeMap and add import statement. But result will be sorted in natural order, not the order you put your values in.